# anyOf equivalent of Kotlin Deferred

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, completable-future

Coroutine `async` returns `Deferred<T>` and there are example of lazy execution and usages of await.

However how can we wait for any one of the `Deffered` instances to complete?

In a nutshell

```
  // whats the equivalent of CompletableFuture.anyOf(...)?
  // is this how we do it? if so how costly is this?
  select<Unit> {
     deffered1.onAwait {}
     deffered2.onAwait {}
  }
```

Comment: also i dont know the coroutine architecture to know how costly is this select but would appreciate if someone could address that as well :)

Comment: You might try cross posting to https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/c/support, I've gotten very quick feedback there.

Comment: @vach you might as well consider having a look at the answers :).

Comment: problem is i dont think thats good solution for this, putting callback on each future will create so much garbage, essentially doing the same as i demonstrate with selector (except selector is more readable)
Lets see if someone from kotlin team can suggest anything better (if not you have the bounty:)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the safest way to do things, but something like this should work:

```
inline suspend fun <T> Iterable<Deferred<T>>.awaitAny(): T {
    var completed: T? = null
    forEachIndexed { index, deferred ->
        deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
            completed = deferred.getCompleted()
            forEachIndexed { index2, deferred2 ->
                if (index != index2) {
                    deferred2.cancel(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    forEach {
        try {
            it.await()
        } catch (ignored: JobCancellationException) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    return completed!!
}
```

Proof: The following prints 1000

```
launch(CommonPool) {
        // 10 - 1 second(s)
        val deferredInts = List(10, {
            val delayMs = (10 - it) * 1000
            async(CommonPool) {
                delay(delayMs)
                delayMs
            }
        })
        val first = deferredInts.awaitAny()
        println(first)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use select expression like this

```
        val deferred1: Deferred<String?> = GlobalScope.async { getValue1() }
        val deferred2: Deferred<String?> = GlobalScope.async { getValue2() }
        val deferred3: Deferred<String?> = GlobalScope.async { getValue3() }

        val deferredList = listOf(deferred1, deferred2, deferred3)
        val firstCompletedResult = select<String?> {
            deferredList.forEach {
                it.onAwait {}
            }
        }
        
        Log.d(TAG, "firstCompleted: $firstCompletedResult")
```

Answer (score 2):

For variety, mentioning [`.merge(): Flow<T>`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/kotlin.collections.-iterable/merge.html) alternative to `select()`, which I used to address [a similar problem](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/171#:%7E:text=get%20the%20first%20in%20a%20collection%20of%20deferreds%20to%20complete%20with%20a%20non-null%20value) (get the first in a collection of deferreds to complete with a non-null value), i.e.

```
val firstCompletedResult = deferreds.map { it::await.asFlow() }.merge().first()
```

or if you like,

```
suspend fun <T> Iterable<Deferred<T>>.awaitAny(): T = map { it::await.asFlow() }.merge().first()
```